# GitHub connecting to an existing project with Android Studio

Tags: android, github, repository

I want to create a repository which my coworker will push his project files into it. When we tried this he did not know how to do it without firstly pulling the existing files which I was created before. But we don't want them. How can he replace his project files over my existing repository files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible and you can do it like this:
First configure AS so that you share the same repository
[image]

Then:

[image]

and finally [image]
In order to replace your files you are working on simply synchronize and commit files!

Answer (score 0):

You (or your coworker) will have to manually remove the files (then commit and push the removals) you don't want. You can do the removal before your coworker clones the repository.